# Change fontsize class option after being set in a format

Tags: fontsize, format-files

I use `mylatexformat` to build easily format files. Consider the following file

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
% This is file t.tex
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

I then run `pdflatex -ini -jobname="myfmt" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx """t.tex"""` to get `myfmt.fmt`. Fontsize is now hardcoded in `myfmt.fmt` and set to `10pt`.

Now, I have another file:

```
%&myfmt
\documentclass{NoMatterItIsNotReadAnyway}
% This is s.tex
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

When I compile it, the format `myfmt.fmt` is used and fontsize is set to `10pt`. Now, I would like to set it to `11pt`. AFAICS, definitions related to fontsize are set inside `size1?.clo` files. So I thought I could go this way

```
%&myfmt
\documentclass{NoMatterItIsNotReadAnyway}
\csname endofdump\endcsname % See mylatexformat documentation
\makeatletter
\input{size11.clo}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work because some macros are already defined and the `\newcommand` check mechanism refuse to go further. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit hackish, but hopefully, it won't break anything.

```
%&myfmt
\documentclass{NoMatterItIsNotReadAnyway}
\csname endofdump\endcsname % See mylatexformat documentation
\makeatletter
% Save orginal definition of \new@command
\let\Oldnew@command\new@command
% Based on \renew@command definition.
% Basically make \newcommand behave like \renewcommand
\def\new@command#1{%
  \let\@ifdefinable\@rc@ifdefinable
  \@testopt{\@newcommand#1}0}
\input{size11.clo}
\let\new@command\Oldnew@command
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

An other way to achieve the same goal is to replace every occurence of `\newcommand` by `\renewcommand` when reading `size11.clo`. I use package `catchfile` that reads a file (`size11.clo`) to a macro and then I `\patchcmd` it (`etoolbox`). Note that the loop is necessary since `\patchcms` replaces only the first occurence of `\newcommand`.

```
%&myfmt
\documentclass{NoMatterItIsNotReadAnyway}
\csname endofdump\endcsname % See mylatexformat documentation
\makeatletter
\usepackage{etoolbox,catchfile}
\CatchFileDef\content{size11.clo}\relax
\newif\ifendofpatch
\endofpatchfalse
\@whilesw\unless\ifendofpatch\fi{%
  \patchcmd{\content}{\newcommand}{\renewcommand}{\endofpatchfalse}{\endofpatchtrue}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `\xpatchcmd*` of `regexpatch` you do a “replace all”.

Comment: @egreg Good to know. I've never heard of that package before.